# How to create a download link that works in all browser

Tags: html, download, zip

I have a zip folder which I want users to download from a simple HTML page.

I have been using this example markup which I got from [this reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp):

```
 <a href="/myzip.zip" download>
```

However, it is not supported on all browsers.

Is there a way to do this that will work on all browsers?

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` headers in your webserver for the corresponding URL.

Specifically, you'd want to set the `Content-Disposition` header to the value `attachment; filename="myzip.zip"` to give it a recommended download filename.

You should set the `Content-Type` header to the value `application/zip` for a zip file.

The means of changing these headers varies widely depending on the actual web server you are using and if you are serving the URL dynamically or statically.

Comment: The `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` headers have been around for a very long time and should be supported by virtually all browsers.

Comment: If this answers your question, you should [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.